# Alt or title attribute for i tag

Tags: html, tags, font-awesome

I use [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) and display their fonts like that:

```
<i class="icon-lock"></i>
```

This will display a nice little lock symbol. For the user to know what exactly that means, I tried adding attributes such as title and alt, but to no avail.

Is there any attribute I can use for the `<i>` tag that executes the same task as alt for images and title for links?

Comment: Many FontAwesome sites also use Bootstrap. If you do, use `.sr-only` on a separate `<span>`.

Comment: Good example with visually hidden inner text: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/other-topics/accessibility

Answer (score 174, accepted):

You can use the `title` attribute on an `i` element, like any element, e.g.

```
<i class="icon-lock" title="This symbolizes your being locked inside"></i>
```

Whether it helps is a more difficult issue. Browsers usually show the `title` attribute value as a “tooltip” on mouseover, but why would the user mouse over the icon? And such tooltips are of poor usability; so-called CSS tooltips often work better.

Screen readers may give the user optional access to `title` attributes, but I’m not sure what they do with elements with empty content.

Comment: `title` is generally read, even with no content, so long as the element itself is selectable

Comment: do note that `<i>` tags are not generally select-able, unless you add a tabIndex to them.

Comment: i have added title in my fa icon  <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true" title="heeeeeelp"></i> but doesn't work

Comment: It should trouble us that this has become accepted and highly upvoted when it's basically wild speculation on Jukka's part. I'm not saying that Jukka was wrong to post it, or that the presence of this answer does harm, but I think the fact that an answer that amounts to "Eh, maybe a `title` attribute will work, or maybe not, who knows?" was deemed good enough to upvote by 120 people illustrates the perfunctory effort that screenreader support gets from most web developers (me included, I admit). As a profession, we need to figure out how to address these problems more rigorously than this.

Comment: **Not good practice from the accessibility point of view**. Not all screen readers will read the title attribute if the host element is not natively focusable (e.g. button, anchor). It's recommended to add in addition to `title` as well a visually hidden text (e.g. `.sr-only` class in Bootstrap). See good examples here: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/other-topics/accessibility

Answer (score 18):

With the advance of [WAI-ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/complete), when using font icons, you probably should use a combination of the following to improve accessibility:

- The role [presentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/complete#presentation) to remove implicit native role semantics of the element. This is especially important if you (ab)use an element with a native semantic to provide icons, as this is the case in your example using the [i](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element) element (which, according to the specs, *"represents a span of text in an alternate voice or mood [...]"*).
- An [aria-label](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/complete#aria-label) to provide a string value that labels the element *-or-* a native HTML [title](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-title) attribute if you are OK with the browser displaying a tooltip when hovered.
- An [aria-hidden](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/complete#aria-hidden) attribute to hide *generated content* from assistive technologies (as you are using an icon font family, there is a generated character :before of :after). According to the specs:

> Authors MAY, with caution, use *aria-hidden* to hide visibly rendered
>   content from assistive technologies only if the act of hiding this
>   content is intended to improve the experience for users of assistive
>   technologies by removing redundant or extraneous content. Authors
>   using aria-hidden to hide visible content from screen readers MUST
>   ensure that identical or equivalent meaning and functionality is
>   exposed to assistive technologies.

---

I don't know your exact use case, so I take the liberty to use the simpler case of providing a phone number. In decreasing order of preference, *I* would use:

```
<span aria-label="Our phone number">
  <span class="icon-phone" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  +33 7 1234576
</span>

(or any variation implying:
  - an `i` element with a `role` presentation attribute
    instead of the inner `span` element
  - a `title` attribute instead of an `aria-label` attribute)
```

```
<span class="icon-phone" 
  aria-label="Our phone number">+33 7 1234576</span>

(or any variation using `title` instead of `aria-label`)
```

```
<i class="icon-phone" role="presentation" 
  aria-label="Our phone number">+33 7 1234576</i>

(or any variation using `title` instead of `aria-label`)
```

Please note that *aria-label* and *title* attributes should describe the **content** of the element. Not the next sibling element. So *I* feel like the following solution is *not* in accordance with the specs (even if most accessibility tools would actually have the same observable behavior as if the phone number were actually inside the `span` element) :

```
<span class="icon-phone" 
  title="Our phone number"></span>+33 7 1234576
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use `<span>` or something along those lines instead. You can use the `title=""` attribute to give some text on hover, if that's what you're looking for. As far as providing accessability to screen readers, or SEO value, you could add the following CSS:

```
.icon-lock{
    text-indent:-99999px;
}
```

And then write your markup like so:

```
<span class="icon-lock">What I want the screen reader to say</span>
```

Comment: `<i>` wasn't deprecated in HTML 4.01.

Comment: You are correct... given that `<u>` and `<s>` were, I always find myself thinking `<b>` and `<i>` were as well, especially since they have `<em>` and `<strong>`, but you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 4):

I think the role for fonts that act like images should be reserved to role="img". This can then be used with aria-label="alt-text". It works because of the ARIA Accessible Name algorithm. See: [Aria Techniques Using Img Role](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/ARIATechnique_usingImgRole_with_aria-label_forCSS-backgroundImage).

Comment: Don't forget to put `aria-hidden='true'` for decorative icons or icons wrapped inside an anchor tag with some text.

Answer (score 3):

`<i>` tags are for marking up text. You are changing the semantic meaning of this tag to something that has nothing to do using italics (and even the italic tag is a bad idea).
You should be using a `SPAN` instead.

Italic elements do not support `alt` attributes, `IMG` elements do. If you want an `ALT` attribute, use an image.

Comment: font-awesome instructions tell you to use `<i>`, so you should probably say what's going to go wrong if you do it that way. Using something (in this case `<i>`) in a way that was not originally intended has risks, but in this case that risk has been mitigated by the fact that thousands of reputable sites with hundreds of millions of users are already using font-awesome.