# Font awesome 5 listen for unknown icons

Tags: css, font-awesome-5

I'm using font awesome 5 on my websites. Let's say I miss-spell a icon like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-map-markerzzzz"></i>
```

Font Awesome code must detect that it's an unknown icon as it displays ? and ! symbols.

Any idea how I can listen in for this? I'd like to add error reporting. We've an error logging system, and I'd like to send an error to that for every broken icon.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: It does not excatly "listen" for this, there's just no matching CSS class that matches fa-map-markerzzzz. Font-Awesome maps the css classes to characters using `.fa-map-marker:after` { content:"\charcode"; }`. However you could create a list of all existing classes and write some simple algorithm to find the closest match and replace the invalid classname with that.

Comment: `<i class="icon-lock" title="This symbolizes your being locked inside"></i>`

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746619/alt-or-title-attribute-for-i-tag]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so much that FontAwesome detects this, since it's a collection of CSS classes backed by a font file and not a piece of code. Therefore, unfortunately there is no error event that you can listen for.

A similar question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825383/how-do-i-dynamically-check-to-see-if-a-remote-font-icon-exists), though not for FontAwesome. It appears that your best bet would be to retrieve a list of existing FontAwesome classes, then compare those to the classes used in your code.

If you use Angular or React, you may be able to wrap the FontAwesome icons in a component and do the error checking there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```html
<style>
.fa:before {
  content:"?"; /*if the content exist it will be replaced later, if not you will see this*/
}

</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" >
<i class="fa fa-map-markerzzzz"></i>
<i class="fa fa-user"></i>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm actually looking for a system where we don't have to manual look. Font Awesome already displays a notification icon where there's a typo. I'm looking for a system to do a sitewide sweep for them.